# Quitar la ultima palabra de un string jquery o javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenos días tengo la siguiente cadena de texto en una variable

```
cad = "perro AND gato AND pajaro AND vaca AND"
```

Como la cadena se crea automáticamente el agrega el AND siempre al concatenar un nuevo elemento, pero para mostrarlo debe quedar sin el ultimo AND.

Como puedo quitar el ultimo AND del string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sabes que lo último en la cadena es AND , puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var cad = cad.substring(cad.length-3)
```

También podrías ver como estas concatenando para que no agregue el último AND.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias a veces se bloquea uno con cosas simples, apenas de el tiempo acepto tu respuesta.

Comment: No hay problema

Answer (score 4):

Si no supieras la longitud de la última palabra:

```js
var cad = "perro AND gato AND pajaro AND vaca ANDabcde...";

cad = cad.split(' ') // separa el string según espacios en blanco
         .slice(0, -1) // toma todos los elementos menos el último
         .join(' '); // vuelve a armar el string

console.log(cad);
```

Comment: Hay que cambiar a   .slice(0, -1)

Answer (score 1):

Esa es mi solución. Por favor lea los comentarios en el código.

```js
let cad = "perro AND gato AND pajaro AND vaca AND ";
//limpia espacios vacios al inix¡cio y final de cadena de texto
cad = cad.trim();
// encuentra la ultima ocurencia de un espacio vacio
var n = cad.lastIndexOf(" ");
//saca en consola la cadena de texto hasta la ultima ocurencia de un espacio vacio
console.log(cad.substring(n, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes hacer lo siguiente, siempre y cuando sepas que al final deja and + un espacio.

```
String  cad = "perro AND gato AND pajaro AND vaca AND";
String eliminar = cad.substring(0, cad.length()-4);
System.out.println(eliminar);
```